# Why "link" header is not supported in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I was trying to pass the "link" tag in headers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Link as mentioned, it only works on Mozilla Firefox and not in other browsers, is there any alternative way? Why is this not implemented in Chrome?

Comment: because they will eventually be evaluated as a <link> html tag,